# Using Google Fit APIs without Google Fit app

Tags: google-fit

Can the Google Fit APIs be used without having the Google Fit APP?

I want to use the Google Fit APIs to count number of steps but can this be done without having to install the Google Fit App.

Comment: You can use the Google Fit REST APIs.

Comment: It was my question and the answer is:  Yes, it can be used.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes** obviously you can use it without application installed . Let me tell you this way ..

1. If you want to that google fit will record step count for your app then you only have to subscribe the Step datatype by using `RecordingApi` of google fit .
2. Use `HistoryApi` to fetch the data from google fit as you want whether in `buckets` or whether it is daily data you want .

I can put some code too if you want . Otherwise you can just follow the [google fit guide](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record) .

**For more clarification some magical lines right from [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/fit/overview) below** .

> The Google Fit app uses the Google Fit platform, which is included in Google Play services. Your fitness or wellness app can use the Google Fit platform without requiring users to install the Google Fit app.

Comment: A sample code will be nice /w nodejs and angularjs.

Comment: Are you looking for sample in `react-native` ?

Comment: nop, need to implement in angularjs web app. I am looking for a code understand how the CRUD will work with GoogleFit. Basically i am working on how to fetch data from GoogleFit and display to user. Not worried about how the user device will update the Google fit dataBase.

Comment: I do not have much idea about `node.js` i am in android technology. If you are looking for integrate `Googlefit`   on web then you need to look for its web samples [Here is one](https://github.com/martzcodes/node-google-fit) it uses rest apis. Keep digging .. have a look at [Google Fit REST API](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/)

Comment: @ADM If google fit app is not installed on my device then how my android app will count steps?

Comment: Health kit is part of play services . Fit is an app by google which shows the data analytics. Read https://developers.google.com/fit/

Comment: @ADM, Can you share sample android studio project where it uses Google Fit REST API? I want to build android app where users can tract steps without installing Google Fit app on their phones. Thanks

Comment: If you want to build Android app why use RestAPis ? Just use FIt SDK . All the APIs you need are documented . Just [get Started](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started) its been evolve since last time i used it. [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit) are samples.

Comment: Can I record steps and retrieve fitness data without installing Google Fit app with the Fit SDK?

Comment: Yeah ... Read the answer above .

Comment: Can you share some source code where it records steps and retrieve steps in real time? It would be great for me as I am new to android. Many thanks

Comment: @ADM, Can you share some code where it counts step in real time without Google Fit installed?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

**Option 1:**

You can go to [fit.google.com](https://fit.google.com/) and manually add activity data. Once you add your activity, the data will be available immediately.

**Option 2:**

From [Google Fit developers site](https://developers.google.com/fit),

> Google fit is an open platform that lets users control their fitness data, developers build smarter apps, and manufacturers focus on creating amazing devices.

Which means, you can use Google Fit APIs to create applications like Google Fit App or the platform can also be integrated directly into several fitness devices which can monitor the fitness data.

So, if you have any other application or a fitness device that pushes data to Google Fit server, you don't need to use Google Fit App.

Comment: My question is if I don't push data but I use google Fit API to fetch buckets but I also don't use FIT, would the step data make sense?